# How can I obtain more feathers?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I want to use the Unlock Potential feature to raise my 4-star heroes into 5-star heroes.

To do so requires Great Badges and Hero Feathers.
Specifically it costs 20 Great Badges and 20,000 Hero Feathers.

The 20 Great Badges seem easy enough to get, beat the training tower on level 6 or higher to get a badge or two.

However I'm stuck on the ***20,000*** Feather requirement, as far as I am aware I can obtain feathers from simple tasks such as:

- Tapping on my friend's hero once a day on the Home page (I've gotten 3-4 each day so far)
- Tapping on one of my heroes once a day on the Home page (whoever has hearts floating around them, gives 5)
- PvP end of season rewards (last week I obtained 1,300ish for my rank)
- Sending heroes home from the Allies page.

The sending home part I am confused about, when I go to "send" different units of the same star value, it usually gives the same amount of feathers, however some units are different, for example:

- Tiki is 3-star, level 21, and will give 300 feathers.
- Wrys is 3-star, level 17, and will give 150 feathers.
- Hana is 3-star, level 1, and will give 150 feathers.
- Lissa is 2-star, level 1, and will give 10 feathers.

Is this due to Tiki just being a better hero than Wrys? Or does the feather value double after a certain level?

I'd like to know so I can determine the best way to obtain Feathers.

In short, I'd like to know:
**What are all the ways to obtain Hero Feathers, and will leveling up heroes yield more feathers?**

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it's possible Tiki gave 300 feathers because she's 20+. Might give even more at level 40+. That's just my guess, however.

Comment: @Nolonar That's what I'm assuming as well, but with her as my only lvl 20+ that is available at the moment I can't check for certain. Hoping someone else can answer, but I might be able to answer my own question in a few more days if not :)

Comment: I just made an observation: I have a 4 star Cain (lvl 1) and a 4 star Lonqu (lvl 29). Either would yield 300 feathers if sent home. A 5 star male Robin (lvl 34) would yield 1000 feathers.

Comment: There may be more ways to get feathers coming soon as well. We've yet to see that 5th battle location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer**:
Best reliable way to get feathers is grind in the Arena. No indication that level affects feathers. Participating in limited time events, such as a Voting Gauntlet is also an excellent source of feathers. You can also get feathers from hero merit, up to 2000 per hero.

**Long Answer**:
I've found useful information in the guide [here](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/fire-emblem-heroes/How_to_Get_Hero_Feathers) or [here](https://rankedboost.com/fire-emblem-heroes/hero-feather/) (they're very similar), but I think you've found almost all sources of feathers, although you didn't mention quests. I've included relevant tables for feather values at the end of the answer.

- Tapping on friends - Greeting your friend should give you 5 feathers. There are some bonus feathers, IGN lists this bonus as 1 per friend, up to 5 total.
- Tapping on hearted heroes - 5 feathers
- Send Heroes Home - Note that I have found no sources that listed heroes to be worth more feathers based on level. Is it possible that your Tiki is 4 star?
- Completing Quests and Missions - Various Arena Quests are worth thousands of feathers
- Arena Rewards - Competing in an arena season can give you a large amount of feathers based upon your performance. You get separate rewards for offense, defense and overall rank.
- Special events - Nintendo may randomly run a special event which distributes feathers, such as the [Global Retweet Event](https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/828800459053883393/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) for 10,000 feathers
- Voting Gauntlet - There are occasionally [Voting Gauntlets](https://feheroes.wiki/Voting_Gauntlet), which can also reward feathers. You 'vote' for your preferred hero and fight battles for them. You will receive 500 feathers any time your hero wins a round, in addition to rank based rewards.
- Hero Merit - A [recent update](http://www.nintendo-insider.com/2017/04/fire-emblem-heroes-update-version-1-2-0-now-available/) added hero merit. You gain merit from battles, and when you accumulate 500 for a hero you receive 500 feathers. [Other sources](https://twitter.com/FEHeroes_News/status/851976560919932928) agree that you can get up to 2000 feathers per hero.

**Sending Heroes Home**
[image]

**Arena Rank Rewards**
[image]

**Arena Offense Rewards**
[image]

**Arena Defense Rewards**
[image]

**Voting Gauntlet Round Rank Rewards**
[image]

**Voting Gauntlet Final Rank Rewards**
[image]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, a pvp season lasts one week each.  So that means in any given week, the maximum amount of feathers you can get (if you are among the top players in the game) is 6205 feathers (4000 for being rank 10+, 1600 for having an offense score of 3001+, 500 for a defense score of 251+, 5 feathers per day from your heroes, 5 feathers a day from friends, 5 feathers per day due to size of friend's list), excluding what you can get from sending heroes home.  That means the best 10 players can only rank up a 4* hero to 5* once every 4 weeks (3.22, but arena awards at end of week).

Comment: @Angzuril In the update [v1.2.0](http://nintendowire.com/news/2017/04/11/fire-emblem-heroes-massive-update-increases-stamina-adds-plenty/), they added *Hero Merit* as a way to obtain feathers

Comment: @Wondercricket Thanks for the reminder. I've edited that in, as well as an additional source for it.