# Why should heroes be sent home?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Besides for feathers [as described here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300047/how-can-i-obtain-more-feathers) what other reason do I have to send heroes home? The base allowance storage of 200 heroes seems quite large. It also seems like I gain little to nothing unless I sacrifice a good hero in which case, is 100 or 200 feathers really better?

That said what reason do I have to keep 1* and 2* heroes as well? What exactly can they be used for, besides feather fodder?

<sub>--- I have no previous FE experience ---</sub>

Comment: I don't know about any additional reasons to send heroes home, but one reason to keep one and two-star heroes is using them to Merge with your higher ranked heroes. This will delete the low-rank hero and give the higher-ranked hero a small amount of SP.

Comment: Fire Emblem Heroes is very different from the classic Fire Emblem games. Prior experience with FE doesn't help much in Heroes.

Comment: @Nolonar, I figured as much, just wanted to include the disclaimer to make it clear :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### EDIT: Since the introduction of Combat Manuals, there is no longer a reason to send heroes home.

**Before**, there was no other reason to send heroes home besides for feathers or to keep the barracks from getting full.

**Now**, converting heroes into Combat Manuals works just as well to keep the barracks from getting full, and can be exchanged for feathers at exactly the same rate as sending heroes home.

Combat Manuals are a way to get rid of heroes (especially duplicates), while still keeping them around for skill inheritance, or until you decide to use them for merging. As such, sending heroes home is now nothing more than a shortcut for creating a Combat Manual, and then exchanging the Manual for feathers.

---

As for why you'd want to turn heroes into feathers:

It's one of the fastest ways to get feathers when there is no event currently going on, like Tempest Trials, Forging Bonds, and so on.

In the arena, you can earn up to 7100 feathers per week. You're much more likely to earn between 1000 and 2000 feathers, though.

As you keep summoning heroes, you'll eventually end up with lots of 3-4 star heroes, which you might not want to keep if you've already decided on which heroes you want in your team. By sending them all home, you can earn between 750 and 1500 feathers per 20 Orbs, assuming you summon the full set of 5 heroes per summoning session.

You'll need all these feathers in order to improve the rarity of your heroes. A 3 star hero needs 2000 feathers to become 4 star, and a 4 star hero needs 20 000 feathers to reach 5 stars. Some heroes can not be summoned at 5 stars and therefore need to be improved using feathers.

If you're not afraid to spend money for orbs, sending heroes provides a limitless source of feathers (limited only by the amount of money you're willing to spend).

Comment: "Besides for feathers"

Comment: @OrangeDog "There is no other reason to send heroes home besides for feathers or to keep the barracks from getting full."

Comment: @Pyritie. To be fair, I added that part after he wrote that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Releasing a hero pays out in feathers.

- One star - 5 Feathers
- Two Star - 10 Feathers
- Three Star - 150 Feathers
- Four Star - 300 Feathers
- Five Star - 1000 Feathers

Comment: Literally the very first sentence says "besides for feathers".